# Updating Pandas MultiIndex after indexing the dataframe

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, multi-index

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
       ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 2), index=index, columns=[0, 1])
s

                     0         1
first second                    
bar   one    -0.012581  1.421286
      two    -0.048482 -0.153656
baz   one    -2.616540 -1.368694
      two    -1.989319  1.627848
foo   one    -0.404563 -1.099314
      two    -2.006166  0.867398
qux   one    -0.843150 -1.045291
      two     2.129620 -2.697217
```

I know select a sub-dataframe by indexing:

```
temp = s.loc[('bar', slice(None)), slice(None)].copy()
temp

                     0         1
first second                    
bar   one    -0.012581  1.421286
      two    -0.048482 -0.153656
```

However, if I look at the index, the values of the original index still appear:

```
temp.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
       labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
       names=[u'first', u'second'])
```

This does not happen with normal dataframes. If you index, the remaining copy (or even the view) contains only the selected index/columns. This is annoying because I might often do lots of filtering on big dataframes and at the end I would like to know the index of what's left by just doing

```
df.index
df
```

This also happens for multiindex columns. Is there a proper way to update the index/columns and drop the empty entries?

To be clear, I want the filtered dataframe to have the same structure (multiindex index and columns). For example, I want to do:

```
 temp = s.loc[(('bar', 'foo'), slice(None)), :]
```

but the index still has 'baz' and 'qux' values:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
       names=[u'first', u'second'])
```

To make clear the effect I would like to see, I wrote this snippet to eliminate redundant entries:

```
import pandas as pd
def update_multiindex(df):
    if isinstance(df.columns, pd.MultiIndex):
        new_df = {key: df.loc[:, key] for key in df.columns if not df.loc[:,     key].empty}    
        new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
    else:
        new_df = df.copy()
    if isinstance(df.index, pd.MultiIndex):
        new_df = {key: new_df.loc[key, :] for key in new_df.index if not     new_df.loc[key, :].empty}
        new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df).T
    return new_df

temp = update_multiindex(temp).index
temp
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'foo'], [u'one', u'two']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: I had this exact problem, I think you'll find that the answer by Ezekiel Kruglick (on this page) solves your problem the best. I added a .unique() to get rid of the duplicates: `df.index.get_level_values(some_level).unique()`

Answer (score 2):

Two points. First, I think you may want to do something that is actually bad for you. I know it's annoying that you have a lot of extra cruft in your filtered indices, but if you rebuild the indices to exclude the missing categorical values, then your new indices will be incompatible with each other and the original index.

That said, I suspect (but do not know) that `MultiIndex` used this way is built on top of `CategoricalIndex`, which has the method [remove_unused_levels()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.remove_unused_categories.html#pandas.CategoricalIndex.remove_unused_categories). It may be wrapped by `MultiIndex`, but I cannot tell, because...

Second, `MultiIndex` is notably missing from the [pandas API documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html). I do not use `MultiIndex`, but you might consider looking for and/or opening a ticket on [GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas) about this if you do use it regularly. Beyond that, you may have to grunnel through the [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/index.py) if you want to find exact information on the features available with `MultiIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your usage pattern you may be able to get the best of both worlds. I'm focusing on:

> This is annoying because I might often do lots of filtering on big
>   dataframes and at the end I would like to know the index of what's
>   left by just doing
>
> df.index
>   df
>
> This also happens for multiindex columns. Is there a
>   proper way to update the index/columns and drop the empty entries?

Consideration (1) is that you want to know the index of what's left. Consideration (2) is that as mentioned above, if you trim the multiindex you can't merge any data back into your original, and also its a bunch of nonobvious steps that aren't really encouraged.

The underlying fundamental is that index does NOT return updated contents for a multiindex if any rows or columns have been deleted and this is not considered a bug because that's not the approved use of MultiIndexes (read more: [github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3686](http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3686)). The valid API access for the current contents of a MultiIndex is  get_level_values.

So would it fit your needs to adjust your practice to use this?

```
df.index.get_level_values(-put your level name or number here-)
```

For Multiindexes this is the approved API access technique and there are some good reasons for this. If you use get_level_values instead of just .index you'll be able to get the current contents while ALSO preserving all the information in case you want to re-merge modified data or otherwise match against the original indices for comparisons, grouping, etc...

Does that fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `droplevel`.

```
temp.index = temp.index.droplevel()

>>> temp
               0         1
second                    
one     0.450819 -1.071271
two    -0.371563  0.411808

>>> temp.index
Index([u'one', u'two'], dtype='object')
```

When dealing with columns, it's the same thing:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

You can also use `xs` and set the `drop_level` parameter to True (default value is False):

```
>>> s.xs('bar', drop_level=True) 
               0         1
second                    
one     0.450819 -1.071271
two    -0.371563  0.411808
```

Comment: This is an undocumented method, as of 0.16.2. Any idea why pandas has no API documentation for `MultiIndex()`?

Comment: No idea why droplevel isn't documented. Here is documentation for the MultiIndex: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

Comment: I do not want to drop the level. My example was basic, but I want to filter a level for multiple values, and eliminate others. I would thus like to have the same structure but only have the right values in the filtered dataframe index and/or columns.

Comment: @user1350191 Can you please clarify your question on the desired index value?

Comment: Please see my edit. Hopefully now it's clearer. @Andreus made a good point though. I might want to be careful with such manipulations. On the other hand, it could be useful in many cases.

Comment: I don't believe there is an easy solution for this.  As @Andreus mentions, you probably don't want to be changing each MultiIndex.  If you did, you would probably need to need to manually create each subindex.

Comment: @Alexander, I understand why one would want to keep the same structure. But it also seems natural to me that one might desire the output I am looking for. The same argument could be made when indexing a normal dataframe. It returns only the selected values in the index, and as such it does not conform to the original dataframe anymore. Does it make sense?

Comment: In which case, remove_unused_levels() from categorical indices may be your best option (as suggested by @Andreus)

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the index of `s` and the index of `temp`:

```
In [25]: s.index
Out[25]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'first', u'second'])

In [26]: temp.index
Out[26]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
           names=[u'first', u'second'])
```

Notices that the `labels` in the `MultiIndex` are different.

Comment: Interesting, I think I get why the levels are still all there, but if effectively they have been eliminated (i.e. there are no labels referring to those values), then why keep them?

Comment: My guess is that it is way more efficient to leave the levels of the MultiIndex as is. If you changed the levels, then you would need to update the labels of the MultiIndex every time you slice.